# How to import a large array in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a single file component with some data:

```
data () {
    return {
        myArray: [obj1,obj2,...obj10000]
    }
}
```

Is it a good idea to have 10000 objects in the data array? If not, how can I import the large array in the single file component?

Comment: Are you actually hard-coding an array with 10000 elements or are you getting this data passed in or generated somewhere?

Comment: I want to be able to edit the array, it's not generated

Comment: So you are actually hard-coding the 10,000 objects into it?  It's not being passed in from anywhere?

Comment: What are these objects for?

Comment: I'm not actually hard coding the large array. Can I import it as a text file? The objects in the array are names of animals

Comment: @Rocke please provide a sample of that text

Comment: So if it's not being hard-coded or being generated, where is the array coming from _exactly?_

Answer (score 2):

You can create it in a separate file and import to component.

```
const animals = [ //animals.js
  {name:"tiger", weight:120},
  {name:"elephant", weight:1000}
]

export default animals
```

In component

```
import animals from './path/to/animals.js'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      animals: animals
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that use a separate json file is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a seperate file in your folder structure under /src /components or wherever.

You shall have two files

1. data.js / data.json
2. ComponentName.vue

**data.js file, could also be a data.json file.**

```
 export const data  =  [{},{},{}]
 export default data;
```

**To import use in any vue component ----**

```
<template></template>
<script>
import data from './components/data' 
*// in case folder structure is different use   " ../ or ./ "*
</script>
```